# Firebase Security UId under Push Id

Tags: javascript, security, firebase

I'm relatively new to firebase security. I've read through all the documentation and I know this should be basic but -

I have a database structure simplified down to this:

```
myapp  
    notifications-settings  
        -thL45hSfjdg123432uX  
            newcontact: true  
            uid: 'unique user id'  
        -L-avI3miwgyhIM35Dor  
            newcontact: true  
            uid: 'unique user id'
```

"uid" is the authenticated user id generated from login using FB or Google. I'm trying to use this rule:

```
"rules": {  
    "notifications-settings": {  
        "$refID": {  
            ".read": "data.child('uid').val() === auth.uid",  
            ".write": "data.child('uid').val() === auth.uid"  
         }  
    }  
}
```

I want to restrict an authenticated user who matches uid from only being able to read and update their newcontact value. It works in that only the authenticated user has access to their newcontact value, however no one has access to notifications-settings which means no one can actually read or update that setting. I get an error on this line in my code:

```
var prefRef = this.afd.app.database().ref('/notifications-settings')
```

Maybe my problem is with trying to access notifications-settings in the code, but I use that in my code to get the nodes like this:

```
prefRef.orderByChild('uid')
    .equalTo(this.userInfoProvider.getUserId()).once('value')
    .then
    (function(snapshot) {
        snapshot.forEach(function (childSnap) {

            childSnap.forEach(function (c)
            {
```

---

Error:

> Uncaught (in promise): Error: permission_denied at /notifications-settings: Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data. Error: permission_denied at /notifications-settings: Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data

Comment: What's the error

Comment: Uncaught (in promise): Error: permission_denied at /notifications-settings: Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data.
Error: permission_denied at /notifications-settings: Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data

Comment: If the rule is this (which I don't want), I don't get the error: "notifications-settings": {
     ".read": "auth != null",
     ".write": "auth != null"
    },